# Doppler Effect in Slow Light

Tags: visible-light, doppler-effect

As experimentally [slow light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light) is possible, i.e. light at or near speed of 20m/s.
So suppose observer in room with slow light moves faster than slow light then would they be
able to experience doppler effect in low light?
Moreover would it be possible to see a same object at many place provided it is travelling significantly fast than slow light.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of slow light in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light)

> Slow light is a dramatic reduction in the group velocity of light, not the phase velocity. Slow light effects are not due to abnormally large refractive indices, as will be explained below.

To clarify,[here is an animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) with different phase and group velocities,

[image: grouphase]

> This shows a wave with the group velocity and phase velocity going in different directions. The group velocity is positive (i.e., the envelope of the wave moves rightward), while the phase velocity is negative (i.e., the peaks and troughs move leftward).

The [Doppler shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect)

> is the change in frequency of a wave in relation to an observer who is moving relative to the wave source.

affects the frequency of a wave,  but the slowing of light is in the group velocity, the [Doppler shift](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/reldop2.html) would be the same as if there is no group velocity just  light moving at c  at the  basic frequency.